# How to sum over a Pandas dataframe conditionally

Tags: python, pandas, sum, conditional-statements, data-science

I'm looking for an efficient way (without looping) to add a column to a dataframe, containing a sum over a column of that same dataframe, filtered by some values in the row. Example:

Dataframe:

```
ClientID   Date           Orders
123        2020-03-01     23
123        2020-03-05     10
123        2020-03-10     7
456        2020-02-22     3
456        2020-02-25     15
456        2020-02-28     5
...
```

I want to add a colum "orders_last_week" containing the total number of orders for that specific client in the 7 days before the given date.
The Excel equivalent would be something like:

```
SUMIFS([orders],[ClientID],ClientID,[Date]>=Date-7,[Date]<Date)
```

So this would be the result:

```
ClientID   Date           Orders  Orders_Last_Week
123        2020-03-01     23      0
123        2020-03-05     10      23
123        2020-03-10     7       10
456        2020-02-22     3       0
456        2020-02-25     15      3
456        2020-02-28     5       18
...
```

I can solve this with a loop, but since my dataframe contains >20M records, this is not a feasible solution. Can anyone please help me out?
Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume your dataframe is named `df`. I'll also assume that dates aren't repeated for a given `ClientID`, and are in ascending order (If this isn't the case, do a groupby sum and sort the result so that it is).

The gist of my solution is, for a given ClientID and Date.

1. Use groupby.transform to split this problem up by ClientID.
2. Use `rolling` to check the next 7 rows for dates that are within the 1-week timespan.
3. In those 7 rows, dates within the timespan are labelled True (=1). Dates that are not are labelled False (=0).
4. In those 7 rows, multiply the Orders column by the True/False labelling of dates.
5. Sum the result.

Actually, we use 8 rows, because, e.g., SuMoTuWeThFrSaSu has 8 days.

What makes this hard is that [rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rolling.html?highlight=rolling#pandas.Series.rolling) aggregates columns one at a time, and so doesn't obviously allow you to work with multiple columns when aggregating. If it did, you could make a filter using the date column, and use that to sum the orders.

There is a loophole, though: you can use multiple columns if you're happy to smuggle them in via the index!

I use some helper functions. Note `a` is understood to be a pandas series with 8 rows and values "Orders", with "Date" in the index.

Curious to know what performance is like on your real data.

```
import pandas as pd

data =  {
    'ClientID': {0: 123, 1: 123, 2: 123, 3: 456, 4: 456, 5: 456},
    'Date': {0: '2020-03-01', 1: '2020-03-05', 2: '2020-03-10',
             3: '2020-02-22', 4: '2020-02-25', 5: '2020-02-28'},
 'Orders': {0: 23, 1: 10, 2: 7, 3: 3, 4: 15, 5: 5}
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Make sure the dates are datetimes
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

# Put into index so we can smuggle them through "rolling"
df = df.set_index(['ClientID', 'Date'])


def date(a):
    # get the "Date" index-column from the dataframe 
    return a.index.get_level_values('Date')

def previous_week(a):
    # get a column of 0s and 1s identifying the previous week, 
    # (compared to the date in the last row in a).
    return (date(a) >= date(a)[-1] - pd.DateOffset(days=7)) * (date(a) < date(a)[-1]) 

def previous_week_order_total(a):
    #compute the order total for the previous week
    return sum(previous_week(a) * a)

def total_last_week(group):
    # for a "ClientID" compute all the "previous week order totals"
    return group.rolling(8, min_periods=1).apply(previous_week_order_total, raw=False)

# Ok, actually compute this
df['Orders_Last_Week'] = df.groupby(['ClientID']).transform(total_last_week)

# Reset the index back so you can have the ClientID and Date columns back
df = df.reset_index()
```

The above code relies upon the fact that the past week encompasses at most 7 rows of data i.e., the 7 days in a week (although in your example, it is actually less than 7)

If your time window is something other than a week, you'll need to replace all the references to a the length of a week in terms of the finest division of your timestamps.

For example, if your date timestamps are spaced are no closer than 1 second, and you are interested in a time window of 1 minutes (e.g., "Orders_last_minute"), replace `pd.DateOffset(days=7)` with  `pd.DateOffset(seconds=60)`, and `group.rolling(8,...` with `group.rolling(61,....)`

Obviously, this code is a bit pessimistic: for each row, it always looks at 61 rows, in this case. Unfortunately `rolling` does not offer a suitable variable window size function. I suspect that in some cases a python loop that takes advantage of the fact that the dataframe is sorted by date might run faster than this partly-vectorized solution.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! I tried this, but I got the following error message:

AttributeError: ("'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'", 'occurred at index Orders')

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Furthermore, I actually simplified the problem a little bit, assuming I could extend the solution to my real problem ;-) In my real data I do not have dates but epoch timestamps. And I do not necessarly want to look back 7 (or any whole number) of days, but possible also 123456 seconds back in time. 

How could we tackle this?

Comment: Regarding the bug, it looks like I'm using a newer feature in pandas. I had the same issue, but setting raw=False in the `apply` in `total_last_week` fixed this. A `FutureWarning` raised suggests raw=False will be the default in the future. I've updated the code above.

Comment: Also responded to your different time windows query above. The main question you need to figure out is: how many rows of data do i need to look at in the `rolling` window to guarantee I have all the information I need? In your original example, I was conservative and said 7+1 = 8 rows, but in your actual example, we could have gotten away with looking at only 3 rows. This is because your dates are spaced at least three days apart. Looking a 3 rows of data is looking at Date - 0 days, Date - 3 days, Date - 6 days. The 4th row would be Date - 9 days, which is outside the 1 week = 7 days range.

Comment: Interesting solution, and it works!
Performance remains an issue though; I tried it with a subset of my data (7.5M rows), using a 7 days range, and I cancelled it after it had ran for an hour.

Found another solution using pandasql sqldf; also slow, but it worked for me (with a lot of patience :-))
Thanks anyway for your help!